# CSS - selector nth-child

Tags: html, css

why all elements were colored on red?

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>1</span>
  <p>2</p>
  <h1>3</h1>
</div>

.parent:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

.parent:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}

.parent:nth-child(3) {
  color: blue;
}
```

I thought that the elements would be properly colored. `span`, `p`, `h1` are the children of the element `div`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.parent:nth-child(1)` means "An element that is the first child of its parent **and** which is a member of the `parent` class".

It won't match the `span`, `p` or `h1` because they do not have `class="parent"`.

The inherit the red colour from their parent which *does* have that class and *is* the first child in its parent.

You need a child or descendant [combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#combinators) in there:

```
.parent > :nth-child(1)
.parent :nth-child(1)
```